# Monitoring Oracle DB remotely

Tags: java, sql, shell, unix, oracle10g

I would like to know how to do this: 
Environment: UNIX
I would like to write a script which can be scheduled to run on a remote machine. It would read the DB details (which is 
residing on another machine) from a config file which looks like this:

```
user=
pass=
product1_SID=
product2_SID=
...
```

Each product has its own database files. So the script should retrieve the details like this:

```
1. Connect to the remote DB.

2. foreach(SID_in_config_file){
        retrieve details from dba_data_files 
        send Resultset to log
   }
3. Close connection
```

Comment: You've made several statements but haven't asked a question.  What is your question?

Comment: How to develop a program for this in Java?

Comment: Seems straightforward: parse the config file, establish a JDBC connection, run the query and write the results to a log file. What's your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Automate the Remote DB Monitoring...which it seems to be....why don't you use TNS entries for each database rather than Product_SIDs. You could easily connect to the databases remotely using TNS entries (all you have to do is put the TNS entries on your source box TNS file).